# How do I get a class instance's values from inside it in Python3?

Tags: python, class, python-3.7

I want to use values defined in **init** in a function.
i.e.

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, thingone):
    self.thingone = thingone
  def printone():
    print(self.thingone)
x = foo(1)
x.printone()
```

but that throws an error that 'self' doesn't exist

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, thingone):
    self.thingone = thingone
  def printone(self):
    print(self.thingone)
x = foo(1)
x.printone()
```

and that throws an error that 'self' isnt given to the function.

How do I access these variables?

Edit: the (1, 2) was a typo and I have fixed it.

Comment: If you want to pass ```1, 2``` to ```foo()``` then you should declare it as ```def __init__(self, thingone, thingtwo):```. The self is automatically passed in.

Comment: Why are you passing 2 arguments in your `foo` when the `init` method only takes one argument, ie `thingone`, make it `__init__(self, var, var2)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the current code throws an error, no? It isn't clear what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take 2 arguments in your `init` method.

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, thingone, thingtwo):
    self.thingone = thingone
  def printone(self):
    print(self.thingone)
x = foo(1, 2)
x.printone()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two arguments have to be passed to the init method, instead of that, you can use args.

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, *thingone):
    self.thingone = thingone
  def printone(self):
    print(self.thingone)
x = foo(1, 2)
x.printone()
# (1, 2)
```